# how to debug google map on release version

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm having an issue with the release version (map is blank) I have tried everything such as building different sha for debugging and release even different key for debugging and release but still nothing, the code is working fine in debug mode but it doesn't work in a live version on google play store.
when I sent mail to tech support they asked me to debug and see the response

> You should be able to debug your own app, please note that my scope of
> support is limited to the Google Maps APIs, downloading your app and
> debugging it is done as best-effort support.

Comment: have you check with realse mode and please check some time user used his kye in debug mode in android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found easy way to get the correct sha key if the app is already published on google play store go to: https://play.google.com/console than select your app and inside you will find tab called integrity open it and copy SHA-1 certificate fingerprint from there.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to check the **Maps API key**, you have to double-check if you inserted the API key for the release version.

Comment: is theres way to debug or listen to google map response on release version ?

Comment: You can build a release version and test it on your device.